# Prove that $n(n+2)$ lies between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$, given n is a positive integer

Tags: inequality

I'm currently trying to prove the inequality
$$n^2<n(n+2)<(n+1)^2$$

Is it possible to solve this without induction?

Comment: Just expand them.

Comment: So I got $n^2<n^2 +2n<n^2 +2n+1$ and
$0<2n<2n+1$ by subtracting $n^2$
is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Since $n$ is positive, $0 < n$, so $0 < 2n$. And, always, $0 < 1$ so $2n < 2n + 1$. Add $n^2$ to all sides, and you have your inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding we get $$n^2<n^2+2n<n^2+2n+1$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Can I subtract $n^2$ from the whole inequality?

Comment: yes, you can subtract the term $n^2$ from the whole inequality.

Comment: We get in this case $$0<2n<2n+1$$ which is true for $$n>0$$

Answer (score 1):

$n(n+2)-n^2=2n>0$

$(n+1)^2-n(n+2)=1>0$

Answer (score 0):

Because $n> 0$

$$n^2 + 2n > n^2$$
trivially.

$$(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 > n^2 + 2n$$

Therefore,

$$n^2 < n(n+2) < (n+1)^2$$